# Maestro Credit Card: Pulling information from MSR dump (Any language)

Tags: magnetic-cards, credit-card-track-data

We have a system that allows you to scan your credit card on a MSR and from the dump I pull the needed fields such as name/cc/exp.  Recently we had to add globalized credit cards to this.  For almost all of the card provided, I was able to still pull the information since they seemed to all follow  a standard.  One exception however was a Maestro card.  The format is completely different, and since I neither have one to verify actual number on card vs dumped data, nore have access to any other dumps, it's very hard for me to figure out the correct format of these.  I also did some google searching with little luck of extracting data from a MSR dump.

Unlike almost all other cards, track one does not start with "%B" and Track two does not start with ";".  Both tracks do appear to end with "?" (based off analyzing the whole dump, not by track).  Track 3 does appear to be empty, which is normal.

The whole dump seems to lack any name data and is basically in the format of:

```
###=###?
###=###=###==#=###?
```

Note that besides the single #, where I had 3 it was variable length.

Again I only had access to one single dump, which for obvious reason I cannot post here.

If anyone has some example code in any language, or can link me to some help, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the card you are testing is faulty or simply a non standard card that is generally not supported? try to check track data from other maestro cards before assuming your system is at fault.

I say this because ISO 7813, the governing standard for transaction cards is pretty clear regarding the fact that track 2 data begins with start sentinel ";" and that all valid bank cards have a format code "B" following the start sentinel "%" in track 1.

check the standard carefully and make sure your system is parsing correctly:
http://www.gae.ucm.es/~padilla/extrawork/tracks.html

Comment: No, Maestro card is a non standard format in the UK. My card is correctly formatted, they just dont follow standards.